# non technical approach to associate contributions with memberships

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Does anyone know of an extension / not technical approach that allows users to manually associate contributions with a membership when they have not been properly associated.

I've seen this happen for various reasons including user and system error. We sometimes write short scripts to fix this by creating entries in the civicrm_membership_payment table when it is easy to know what should be linked with what but it would be nice if users could do this on a one to one basis, 1) so they don't have to ask a developer and 2) for those times when it is not obvious what should happen (multiple memberships, contribution types, etc.)

Comment: Don't know of any extension, but would be interested if this was available. Now I always have to ask the developer to do it. If something like this will become available, I am very willing to test/review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[org.civicoop.membershippayment](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.membershippayment) does this and only this.

Comment: Looks great. Thanks @jon

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension that does that: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.membership

It can do much more than only connecting memberships and contributions via the UI so make sure that it's not an overkill for your purposes ;)

Unfortunately, there is no coherent documentation so for some features you may want to contact the maintainer (Björn from SYSTOPIA) for info and/or add to the documentation once you know your way around the extension.